# Why isn't VS Code debugger working on python?

Tags: package-management, python, python3, numpy

Everytime I try to import numpy, the VS Code debugger won't work, giving the output

> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py", line 16, in < module>;
>       from . import multiarray
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray' from 'numpy.core' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py)

The code works fine if I run it on terminal, also does the vs code debugger if I don't import numpy. I tried uninsatalling and reinstalling numpy and nothing changed.

I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Visual Studio Code 1.39.0, Python 3.7.4, Numpy 1.7.5.

Comment: I have the same issue! Have you resolved this?